# Error with adjmulticols package

Tags: errors, multicol, adjmulticol

I'm writing an article with LaTeX and I would like to create a legend formatted on two column with a margin (using the `adjmulticol` package) inside a figure environment.

When I build my file I have the following error :

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{adjmulticols} on input line 11 ended by \end{multicols}.
```

and I don't understand why because I my `\begin{adjmulticols}` environment doesn't end with `\end{multicols}`.

I tried to disable the `\usepackage{multicol}` by commenting the line but the error remain.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%~ \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{MyFigure.jpg}
\begin{adjmulticols}{2}{2cm}{2cm}
My two column legend.
\end{adjmulticols}
\caption{My caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Do you know why this error happen and how to correct it to make my code compile fine ?**

---

I'm building my file with XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is corrected in the new release.  Please check https://github.com/borisveytsman/adjmulticol and (in a couple days, when v1.2 hits the mirrors) https://ctan.org/pkg/adjmulticol

Answer (score 4):

Open a bug report with adjmulticols. It seems to get the case of being inside a box wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjmulticol}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    multicol in a box is fine
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \begin{adjmulticols}{2}{2cm}{2cm}
    but this is not 
  \end{adjmulticols}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://github.com/borisveytsman/adjmulticol/issues/1 . Used this occasion to move the repository from cvs to git

Answer (score 0):

I recently got into this problem, too. The last portion of the text were missing from the `adjmulticol` environment defined as

```
\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0pt}{-\marginparwidth}
...
\end{adjmulticols}
```

After struggling for days, I realised that there was a file in my latex dir called `multicol-2019-10-01.sty`

Substituting the standard `multicol.sty` with this, I solved my problem. However, I cannot explain why...